# what is the best for me ubuntu18.04 or ubuntu 19.10 i'm master student and i need stable and fast and new version of ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

i want to use good and stable and fast and updated version of ubuntu also able to install new versions of python library and all required program in my master study like new version of tensorflow and so on

Comment: your question is asking for stable and newer which is not possible.. either use 18.04 Lts 0r 19.10 latest

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not important. Whether system works.

**But** if your study needs some special conditions, like CUDA, then always use LTS versions like 18.04 to decrease some unnecessary problems.

**AND** if your are also required to handle something about Linux, try use Archlinux in the virtual machine.

Comment: TensorFlow isn't in the default repos of either 18.04 or 19.10, so hatem will have to install lots (gigabytes) of extra packages either way.

Comment: @karel I was talking about CUDA, not Tensorflow. It would be more panic if you can not get your CUDA right. Deep learning framework problems can be easily solved by using conda or nvidia-docker.

Comment: I know what you're talking about. That's why I wrote the word "gigabytes" in the previous comment. NVIDIA + CUDA + Tensorflow = *gigabytes* of extra installed packages. The Ubuntu iso itself is only ~2 GB to download.

Comment: thank you for your answer now i use ubuntu 19.10 but i have more problems so i ask this question to return to ubuntu 18.04